# Event listener prevents another event listener from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a navigation that uses an event listener (`click`) to move through it, and then I have a <kbd>start</kbd> button that disables the navigation, so that some automation occurs. My problem is that when you load the page, click the <kbd>start</kbd> button, the navigation event handler removes the event like its supposed to. But when I reload the page, click on the navigation BEFORE I click on <kbd>start</kbd>, the <kbd>start</kbd> button will no longer work after that - it doesn't even fire at all (tested with some alerts)

navigation code:

```
var hrNav = document.getElementById('hrNav');
    var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');

    //Check to see if the user is on an iPad or iPhone
    var isiPad = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) != null;

//EVENT LISTENER FOR NAVIGATION 
//If the user is on an iphone or ipad, use the touchstart event listener rather than click. Use click otherwise, or use onclick for IE users.
    if (isiPad == true) {
        hrNav.addEventListener('touchstart', highlight);
    } else {
        if(hrNav.addEventListener){  
            hrNav.addEventListener('click', highlight); 
            } else {  
                hrNav.attachEvent('on'+'click', highlight);
        }
    }

    //EVENT LISTENER FOR START BUTTON
if (isiPad == true) {
    startButton.addEventListener('touchstart', start);
} else {
    if(startButton.addEventListener){  
        startButton.addEventListener('click', start);
        } else {  
            startButton.attachEvent('on'+'click', start);
    }
}

    //Function for start button
function start(e) {
hrNav.removeEventListener('click', highlight);
}

    //Function for navigation
    function highlight(ev) {
     //Do Stuff
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery; I don't see any.

Comment: What are you doing in highlight? Any console errors?

Comment: It's tagged with jQuery, incase someone has a better solution using jQuery.  There are no console errors. The highlight function is just changing some css for the navigation, as well as doing some AJAX to get the associated content for each navigation item.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bboone/VyNdF/1 - works fine in Chrome. I'm suspecting the highlight function as well (or some other piece of code that's manipulating events).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event listener doesn't remove after it fires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480868/event-listener-doesnt-remove-after-it-fires)